# MediaSource extension in Chrome mobile

Tags: iphone, google-chrome, mobile, media-source

Wondering if anybody knows if/when the Chrome mobile will implement MediaSource Extension (MSE)?  Got version 30.0 on my iphone 5 and it fails the demo test (http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/media-source.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe we have it on Chrome Desktop and Android (but I could be mistaken).  Regardless, we can only use the WebKit renderer on iOS so the features you see on Android are not always going to be present on iOS because we have less control.

To track the status in Android visit [ChromeStatus](http://www.chromestatus.com/features/4563797888991232) (which reports it is in M30 - currently the beta as of 27th Sept 2013)

Comment: thought Chrome used the majority of WebKit under the hood.  Saw a wiki post that under 2013 some of that is shifting over to Blink.  Not sure I follow the effects on mobile devices.  How can I follow MSE support on mobile?

Comment: It did use webkit, but that doesn't mean all ports share the same feature set, the main thing though is on iOS you have to use the WebView that Apple give you, you can't deploy your own.  It will be in M30 (next release) of Android http://www.chromestatus.com/features/4563797888991232